# System.Windows.Markup namespace for Windows Store apps

Tags: windows-store-apps, xml-namespaces

I want to use the xmlnsdefinitionattribute which is defined in System.Windows.Markup. But the **.net library for Windows Store** does not include the namespace **System.Windows.Markup**. The **System.Windows.Markup** is in the library **System.Xaml**.

Can I add a reference of **System.Xaml** to windows store apps and will be approved by the store or will the app be rejected during the approval process because System.Xaml should not be used for windows store apps.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you cannot.

It should be noted that the `XmlnsDefinition` `struct` exists in `Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup`. One interface in this this is [`IXamlMetadataProvider`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.markup.ixamlmetadataprovider.aspx), which I believe may allow you to do what you are asking. It has a method `GetXmlnsDefinitions` which returns an array of `XmlnsDefinition`.